# Every time a new swing windows opens in code that is executed in a for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

Every time a new swing windows opens in code that is executed in a for loop.

I have some code that is runned in a for loop. 
The for loop gives every time a new value to my multidimensional array.

But, every time my for loop creates open's a new windows but does not close the old window.
How can I solve this issues? I want to close the old windows and refresh my window with the new actual values or that only one Windows is opened and that the new values of the for loop refreshes the values inside the table based on the multidimensional array names data.

Because now more than 200 (every second a new windows is opened) windows are opened and after 1 minute I don’t see new values appearing on my window and the computer freezes.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class UAppWin {

    private static final int Status_COL = 1;

    String[][] data = new String[3][3];
    int dptr;

    String[] cols = { "Feature", "Status", "Value" };

    public UAppWin(String label, int nphases) {
        System.out.println("UApp \"" + label + "\" (" + nphases + " phases)");
    }

    void newCycle(int phasenr) {
        System.out.println("UApp =============================");
        dptr = 0;
    }

    void addEntry(int index, double tim, String label, int status, double dval) {
        System.out.println("Uapp [" + index + "] " + label + "(" + status + ") " + dval);

        data[dptr][0] = label;
        data[dptr][1] = "" + status;
        data[dptr][2] = "" + dval;
        dptr++;

    }

    void addMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Uapp alert: " + msg);
        // rode balk met bericht
    }

    void deleteMessage() {

    }

    void endCycle() {
        System.out.println("UApp =============================");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(getNewRenderedTable(getTable())));
            }
        });

    }

    private JTable getTable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
        return new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 150);
            }
        };
    }

    private static JTable getNewRenderedTable(final JTable table) {
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
                String Status = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, Status_COL);
                if ("0".equals(Status)) {
                    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else if ("2".equals(Status)) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                    setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return this;
            }
        });
        return table;
    }

}
```

The second part of the code edited:

```
public class HmOpIntf {
    static final String DFLT_IP_ADDR = "127.0.0.1";
    static final int    DFLT_IP_PORT = 9502;
    static final int    DFLT_MB_UNIT = 1;
    static final int    DFLT_POLL_TM = 2;


    public static ModbusClient connectPLC(String ipAddr, int port, int unitNr)
    {
        ModbusClient mc = null;
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + ipAddr + " port " + port + " unit " + unitNr);
        try {
            mc = new ModbusClient(ipAddr, port);
            mc.Connect();
            mc.setUnitIdentifier((byte)unitNr);
            mc.WriteSingleCoil(0, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("*** connectPLC: exception caught");
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        return mc;
    }

    public static void disconnectPLC(ModbusClient mc)
    {
        mc = null;
    }


    public static String MyConvertRegistersToString(int[] regs, int startIx, int len) {
        char[] ca = new char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ca[i] = (char) regs[startIx + i];
        }
        return new String(ca);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModbusClient mc = null;
        String ipAddr = DFLT_IP_ADDR;
        int ipPort = DFLT_IP_PORT;
        int mbUnit = DFLT_MB_UNIT;
        int pollTime = DFLT_POLL_TM;

        int tlBase = 2000; /* Offset in PLC's holding registry */
        int tlBlocksz = 84;
        String[] tlLabel = {"T4 mould", "T injection valve"};  /* Default */
        int trafLightNum = tlLabel.length;
        String[] colors = { "green", "yellow", "red" };
        int status;

//        Notifications.infoBox("Hello world!", "Welcome message");
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            if (args.length < 4) {
                System.err.println("*** Error (" + args.length +"): arguments are: ip-addr port unit polltime label-1 ...");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            ipAddr = args[0];
            ipPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            mbUnit = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            pollTime = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }
        if (args.length > 4) {
            trafLightNum = args.length - 4;
            tlLabel = new String[trafLightNum];
            for (int i = 0; i < trafLightNum; i++) {
                tlLabel[i] = args[i + 4];
            }
        }

//        Scope sc = new Scope();
//        sc.runScope();

        if ((mc = connectPLC(ipAddr, ipPort, mbUnit)) == null) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to connect to PLC");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        TrafficLight tlLast = null;
        int[] values = new int[tlBlocksz];
        TrafficLight[] tl = new TrafficLight[trafLightNum];
        Scope[] sc = new Scope[trafLightNum];
        Notifications nots = new Notifications(trafLightNum);
        int locX, locY;
        for (int i = 0; i < tl.length; i++) {
            tl[i] = new TrafficLight();
            tl[i].setLbl(tlLabel[i]);
            tl[i].setVisible(true);
            if (tlLast != null) {
                locX = tlLast.getLocation().x;
                locY = tlLast.getLocation().y + tlLast.getHeight();
            } else {
                locX = tl[i].getLocation().x;
                locY = tl[i].getLocation().y;
            }
            tl[i].setLocation(locX, locY);
            sc[i] = new Scope(tlLabel[i], locX + tl[i].getWidth(), locY, 320, 290 /* tl[i].getHeight()-80 */ );
            sc[i].setGrid(10, 5);
            tlLast = tl[i];
        }
        UAppWin uw = new UAppWin("RTM Facility",  5);
        int phase = 1;

//        tl2.setVisible(true); tl2.setLocation(tl.getWidth(), 0);
        try {
            double t = 0.0;
            int[] dreg = new int[2];
            for (;;) {
                uw.newCycle(phase);
                for (int i = 0; i < tl.length; i++) {
                    values = mc.ReadHoldingRegisters(tlBase + i * tlBlocksz, values.length);
                    status = values[0];

                    if (status >= 0 && status < colors.length) {
//                        System.out.println(i + ": " + colors[status]);
                        if (status == 0) tl[i].greenOn();
                        else if (status == 1) tl[i].yellowOn();
                        else tl[i].redOn();
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Status value " + i + " out of range: " + status);

                    dreg[0] = values[1]; dreg[1] = values[2];
                    double dval = (double) ModbusClient.ConvertRegistersToFloat(dreg);
                    sc[i].addValue(t, dval);
                    sc[i].drawSignal();
                    // w.addEntry(int i, float t, String label, int status (o = groen, 1 = yellow, 2 = red), float dval);
                    uw.addEntry(i, t, tlLabel[i], status, dval);

                    int msglen = values[3];
                    if (msglen > 0) {
                        String msg = MyConvertRegistersToString(values, 4, msglen);
                        System.out.println("DEBUG: received message for " + tlLabel[i] + ": " + msg);
                        nots.notify(i, msg);
                        uw.addMessage(msg);
                    }
                    else {
                        nots.notify(i, null);
                        uw.deleteMessage();
                    }
//                    System.out.println("Received for set " + i + ": status=" + status + " dval=" + dval + " msglen=" + msglen);
                }
                uw.endCycle();
                t += 1.0;
                Thread.sleep(pollTime * 500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to communicate with PLC - exit");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            mc.Disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Failed to disconnect from PLC");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the `for` loop ?

Comment: @Arnaud I added the second class to my code

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) `HmOpIntf` Use descriptive class names.

Comment: If you can hide a JFrame that you don't want to see any more by using "setVisible(false)", You might want to check the functionality of "dispose()" if you don't want to use the window ever again.

Comment: @matt where should I add the setVisible(false) let say i want the window to be close after 2 seconds?

Comment: I cannot even find where you're creating the windows. Is it at the JOptionPane.showMessage?

Comment: @matt yes indeed

Comment: Maybe instead of creating a JOptionPane, you can just create a JFrame one time, and then where you create the JOptionPane, call JFrame.setContentPane and use the JScrollPane you've been adding to the JOptionPane?

Comment: @matt how would that look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UappWin` seems to be tied to a window. So when you create it, also create a `JFrame`. Then nothing else would need to change except the run method and declaring the JFrame.

```
public class UAppWin {
    private JFrame frame;

    public UAppWin(String label, int nphases) {
        //System.out.println("UApp \"" + label + "\" (" + nphases + " phases)");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("UApp \"" + label + "\" (" + nphases + " phases)");


        frame = new JFrame("title");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Then when you create the window.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(getNewRenderedTable(getTable())));
              frame.setContentPane( new JScrollPane( getNewRenderedTable( getTable() ) );
              frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should probably ask a new question as that is completely different. Also, if you could reduce the problem down to a small repeatable example it would help.